# Вытаскивание IP из строки

Tags: python

Допустим у меня есть строка типа такой:

```
from rw-sc-22 (wellknown [94.26.18.9])
```

Как с помощью инструментов Python без изобретания велосипеда я могу вытащить из нее IP-адрес ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

регулярным выражением

```
import re

str = "from rw-sc-22 (wellknown [94.26.18.9])"

result = re.search('\[(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\]', str)

print result.group(1)
```

Answer (score 9):

Из данной строки, простейший метод такой:

```
mystr = "from rw-sc-22 (wellknown [94.26.18.9])"
mystr.split("[")[1].split("]")[0]
```